# Showing tokens in UITextField

Tags: iphone, cocoa, uitextfield, token

I want to get tokens appearance in UITextField as we have in NSTokenField ie.

> as soon as user enters some name in
>   UITextField it gets enclosed within a
>   token.

We have this control in to-cc fields in mail in iPhone / iPod and I want to get similar feature in my application.

Can anyone suggest me some solution for it??

Thanks,

Miraaj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`TTMessageRecipientField`](http://api.three20.info/interface_t_t_message_recipient_field.html) control does this, so you might be able to just repurpose that control.